# SWIG TypeError Building Python Module

Tags: python, typeerror, swig

I am trying to create a python module using SWIG. However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: in method 'Foo', argument 1 of type 'std::vector< std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > >,std::allocator< std::vector< std::string,std::allocator< std::string > > > > &'
```

I've tried putting "std::" in front of the vector types, I've tried putting "using namespace std;", and I've tried including "std_vector.i." I have not had any luck resolving the issue.

How can I get rid of this error?

myModule.i

```
%module myModule

%{
 #include "myModule.h"

/* Function declarations */
    void foo(std::vector <std::vector <std::string> > &input, Model *myModel,std::vector <std::vector <std::vector <double> > > &output)
%}
using namespace std;
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"

// Instantiate templates used

 %template(VecInt) vector<int>;
 %template(VecVecInt) std::vector<std::vector<int> >;
 %template(VecDouble) std::vector<double>;
 %template(VecVecDouble) std::vector<std::vector<double> >;
 %template(VecString) std::vector<std::string>;
 %template(VecVecString) std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >;
 %template(VecConstChar) std::vector<const char*>;


#include "myModule.h"

    void foo(std::vector <std::vector <std::string> > &input, Model *myModel,std::vector <std::vector <std::vector <double> > > &output)
```

Foo Function:

```
  void foo(vector <vector <string> > &input, Model *myModel,vector <vector <vector <double> > > &output)
```

Comment: When are you getting the error (isn't there more text related to it)? Looks like a *Python* error (meaning it's at runtime). The code that generates the error? A little bit more context? *OS*, *Python*, *swig*, compiler versions? Maybe the `foo` implementation?

Comment: I'm almost positive it's a SWIG error. I am compiling the programing in the terminal via MacOS. It's the latest version of SWIG. I can assign the variables fine. But when I try to call the function Foo in python, that's when I get the error. Most other posts claim the error have to do with either how SWIG recognizes vectors (or rather does not).